# Method determineTargetUrl in Spring Security 4 not being called

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have a `CustomLoginSucessHandler` in my Spring MVC 4 project to manage an action when the user Logs In.

This is working properly. In the same class I have the method `determineTargetUrl` to redirect the user according to his `ROLE`.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final String userName = authentication.getName();       
        log.debug("TARGET URL METHOD!");
         List<Authority> authorityList = authorityService.getAllAuthoritiesByUserName(userName);

         for(Authority authority: authorityList){
             switch (authority.getAuthority()){

             case "ROLE_ADMIN": 
                 return "processFile";

             case "ROLE_USER":
                 return "userPortal";

             case "ROLE_DEMO1":
                 return "processFile";

             case "ROLE_DEMO2":
                 return "processFile";                      
            }            

         }
        return "403";   



    }
```

See that I have a `log.debug("TARGET URL METHOD")`

This log is never called and of course the page is not being redirected, it's going to the default landing page that is `processFile.html`.

I am puzzled why the second method is not being called while my `onAuthenticationSuccess` works perfectly. They are in the same Class.

Here is the code how I create the instance of my `CustomLoginSucessHandler`:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLoginSucessHandler customLoginSucessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll().and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403.html");

        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher());
        http.formLogin().successHandler(customLoginSucessHandler);  

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are trying to ovverride the wrong function, that is the root cause of your issue.** In the excerpt you provided you have a function that *seems to be overriding* another:

```
@Override
protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
```

**but in fact it is not overriding anything.** If you check the javadoc of [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), you will see that it provides only one function: `onAuthenticationSuccess` which you reported as "working". It works, but it is an overriden function and it does get called as part of the standard login procedure. If you follow closely this example:

[CustomLoginSuccessHandler example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login) *(probably you followed this already)*

you will see that the `determineTargetUrl` function is not overriden, but explicitly called by the implementation:

```
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
```

which handle method in turn is also being called from:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    handle(request, response, authentication);
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}
```